# Using NIFI how do you apply attributes to files in a zip from a json file also contained in the same zip?

Tags: json, apache-nifi, unpack

Using Apache Nifi I'd like to process a zip which contains a category.json file and a number of data files as illustrated.

```
somefile.zip
├──category.json
├──datafile-1
├──datafile-2
├──...
├──datafile-n
```

Example category.json

```
{
  "category": "history",
  "rating" : 5 
}
```

What I'd like to do is unpack the files and apply the category.json data as attributes to each datafile.

What would be the best way to handle this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Myabe not the best one, but a way to do it :

1) unzip
2) use routeOnAttribut based on category.json filename
3) retrieve category as attribut in category.json flowfile
4) zip all file again but keep atttribut
5) unzip again and keep attribut, all your flowfile will have the category attribut

Comment: Thank you, I'll give it a try tomorrow and post back.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend starting with a combination of `ListFile` and `FetchFile` (or `GetFile` on its own) to retrieve the archive, [`CompressContent`](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.9.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.CompressContent/index.html) to extract the component files, `RouteOnAttribute` using the flowfile filename attribute to separate the flowfile containing `category.json`, and the [`EvaluateJSONPath`](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.11.4/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.EvaluateJsonPath/index.html) processor to retrieve the JSON content of that flowfile and populate certain values into attributes.

From there, it's unclear if your question is how to update the NiFi flowfile attributes for each flowfile containing one of the data files from that archive, or apply the extracted JSON to the data files on disk somewhere.

Assuming the former, you could either write the extracted JSON into a variable or parameter (use [`ExecuteScript`](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-scripting-nar/1.11.4/org.apache.nifi.processors.script.ExecuteScript/index.html) to do so) and use [`UpdateAttribute`](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-update-attribute-nar/1.11.4/org.apache.nifi.processors.attributes.UpdateAttribute/) to apply those attributes onto the other flowfiles resulting from the `CompressContent` processor.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The idea is to apply the json data as attributes to each of the flow files containing data files. Example: The flowfile for `datafile-1` would contain the attributes `category:history` and `rating:5`.  Flowfile for `datafile-2` would contain the same attributes.